# Convert serial port data to float in C with union

Tags: c, floating-point, serial-port, unions

I'm using a C program on Linux to read data from a serial port.

The data to read comes from Code Composer Studio from the line:  `UART_writePolling(uartHandle, (uint8_t*) &value, sizeof(float));`

`value` is the float I want to read in C, where `value = 1.5`.

When I read in the data from the serial port, in C, into a buffer and print with `printf("%u\n", (int)buffer[i]);`

I get `value` to be:

```
0     
0
4294967232
63
```

and when I insert `buffer[i]` into `a.array` and print with
    `printf("%d\n", a.array[i]);`
I get `value` to be:

```
0
0
-64
63
```

I've also tried using unions:

```
    unsigned int value = 0;
    for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--){
        //value <<= 8;
        value = value + (int)a.array[i+8+j];
    }
    printf("value: %u\n", value);
    data.u = value;
    printf("(float): %f\n", data.f);
```

which doesn't give the correct answer.

How can I use union to get the correct data as a float?
Do I need to use `<<`?

EDIT: better idea of the code

```
//headers

typedef struct {
  int *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}
... //more functions/code to resize array and free the memory later

union Data {  
    float f;
    unsigned int u;
};

int main(){
    union Data data;       

    //open serial port code

    char buffer[1]; /* Buffer to store the data received,
                            reading one at a time */

    Array a;
    initArray(&a, 5); /* initialise an array to store the read data
                         that is read into buffer*/

    //while loop to read in data for some amount of time/data
        int b_read = 0; 
        b_read = read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 

        for (int i=0; i<b_read; i++){
            printf("%u\n", (int)buffer[i]); 
            // how the first set of values above were printed

            insertArray(&a, buffer[i]);  
            // also adding the values read to buffer into array a   
        }
    //end while

    // close the port 

    for(int i=0; i<no. of elements in array a; i++){ 
        printf("%d\n", a.array[i]);  
    // how the second set of results were printed
    }

     //below is an attempt at using union and <<:
     unsigned int value = 0;
        for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--){
            //value <<= 8;
            value = value + (int)a.array[i+8+j]; //index used is particular to my code, where value is in a specific place in the array
        }
        printf("value: %u\n", value);
        data.u = value;
        printf("(float): %f\n", data.f);
        //these printfs don't give a reasonable answer

    // free memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code you posted is not complete.  What is `a`?  What is `data`?

Comment: What is buffer ?

Comment: You're on the right track at least, `0x3fc00000` is the hexadecimal representation of `-1.5f`(where `0x3f` is 63 and `0xc0` is -64, of course).

Comment: @Tom's: `buffer` is an array of some 8-bit integer type. Since this is commonly what is used for a buffer when reading bytes from a serial port, you can conjecture it and then confirm by looking at the values the OP shows from printing the individual elements `buffer[i]`. Those are the values one would obtain from printing the individual bytes of a `float`.

Comment: @Tom's `buffer` is what I read the serial port data into, as @Eric has said above. I go through this `buffer` array to find the numbers corresponding to what `value` should be, and I have printed the results above.

Comment: @unwind That's good to know

Comment: I do not have experience with reading serial port data, but when reading socket, there is a format in order to adapte the data to all machine : htonl() , htons(), ntohl() , ntohs(). Is there anything like that for reading serial port ? Because without further thinking, I'd say : just "printf("%f", (float)buffer);". No ?

Answer (score 1):

Once the bytes are in `buffer` starting at offset `i`, you can reinterpret the bytes as a float with:

```
float f;
memcpy(&f, buffer+i, sizeof f);
```

To use a union, you could use:

```
union { uint32_t u; float f; } x;
x.u = value;
float f = x.f;
```

However, this requires that `value` contain all 32 bits that represent the `float`. When you attempted to construct the value with:

```
//value <<= 8;
value = value + (int)a.array[i+8+j];
```

There are two issues. First, `value <<= 8` is needed. I presume you tried it first and did not get a correct answer, so you commented it out. However, it is required. Second, this code to insert the bytes one-by-one into `value` is order-dependent. Once the shift is restored, it will insert greater-addressed bytes into less-significant bits of `value`. Systems generally arrange bytes in objects in one of two orders: More significant bytes in lower addresses or more significant bytes in greater addresses. We do not know which order your system uses, so we do not know whether your code to insert the greater-addressed bytes in less significant bytes is correct.

Note: The above assumes that the bytes are read and written in the same order, or that issues of endianness have already been handled in other code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will need to try this. As for the order, the following data: `{ 0x0102, 0x0304, 0x0506, 0x0708 }` is received as `21436587` in my C code.

Answer (score 0):

You use printf with %u but cast into a int. So maybe it's not surprising to have this behavior since 2^32 = 4294967296, and 4294967296 - 64 (your second printf result) = 4294967232 (your first printf result).

Just cast into "unsigned" if you use "%u" or cast into "int" if you use "%d".